# Android views randomly incomplete or not drawn at all

Tags: android, view, rendering

i have a problem with the gui in my android (smartphone) application.

At startup everything is fine, but after some time the GUI starts to get messed up. Some elements ore not drawn completely, sometimes im getting a full black screen in some of my tabs. And some animations do not work anymore.

I already tried to switch off hardware acceleration in application and activities, but that did not help at all.

The appearence of the bug is rather random, but i have the feeling that switching between background and foreground sometimes triggers it.

The application is rather dynamic. I have 4 tabs that are shown in a self programmed tab view, so everything is running in one activity. the content of the tabs also changes by user input or other triggers. This is done by loading predefined xml views and animations.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now resolved the problem by refactoring the whole project and use the fragments api of android to generate my views instead of using my own solution.
I still have no clue why the rendering of views randomly failed or produced incomplete views without any log errors but perhaps this will help others with the same problems.